# How to test Django app with multitenancy on localhost

Tags: django, multi-tenant, hosts

I am developing a Django app that works with multitenancy through the django-tenant-schemas library. We bind subdomains to our tenants. I need to test a data migration locally before I run it on production but the problem I'm running into is that I cannot access all the tenants. What I need to do is use the application, click buttons and see if everything still works, posing as multiple of our clients.

We currently have it set up so that the public schema is bound to `127.0.0.1` on my local machine and our own tenant to `localhost`. On our staging / production it would be client.ourdomain.com, but as I understand -and tested- it you cannot work with subdomains on localhost, so I'm lost on how to get access to the other tenant schemas.

I have tried to edit my /etc/hosts file to bind the following 2 but those don't work:

```
localhost client.localhost
127.0.0.1 client.localhost
```

This seems like it would be a problem many people run into but I cannot seem to find good info on how to do this both [in the official docs](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [elsewhere](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants/issues/25), although the second link looks to be what I need but they suggest what I already tried.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could bind client1.example.test, client2.example.test etc. to your 127.0.0.1 ip.

Comment: I tried this but the issue I'm running into is that my development server is running on port 8000 and you cannot specify that in the hosts file. I looked if it's possible to run Django on port 80 but it's not recommended

Comment: I tried to fix that by adding a reverse proxy from port 80 to port 8000 but that also doesn't solve my problem since I also have a frontend on another port that I cannot reach then

Comment: How about adding an option to your frontend to specifiy full host, that way you could just tell it to connect to http://client1.example.test:8000 (and of course, take care of CORS headers) - https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers